# jQuery Validation Plugin: Using Multiple errorLabelContainers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that, where depending on the selected value of the userAction radio group, either the loginFields or signupFields are shown.  Also, I have two error containers - errorMessageLogin and errorMessageSignup - to display error messages respective to the selected value of the userAction:

```
<div id="errorsSection">
    <div id="errorMessageLogin">
        <!-- Login Error Messages go here -->
    </div>                

    <div id="errorMessageSignup">
        <!-- Signup Error Messages go here -->
    </div>
</div>
<div id="contentSection">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
<div id="formSection">
    <form id="myForm">
        <input name="userAction" type="radio" value="login" checked="checked">Login</input>
        <br />
        <input name="userAction" type="radio" value="signup">Sign Up</input>

        <div id="loginFields" style="display:none">
            <!-- Login fields: email address and, password -->
        </div>

        <div id="signupFields" style="display:none">
            <!-- Signup fields: name, age, email address, and password -->
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I'm using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) like this:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        MyWebService.DoWork(form);
    },
    rules: myRules,
    errorLabelContainer: null, // how to determine at runtime?
    messages: myMessages,
    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).prev().addClass(errorIcon);
        $(element).addClass(errorClass);
        $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").addClass(errorClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).prev().removeClass(errorIcon);
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
        $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").removeClass(errorClass);
    }
});
```

I highlight invalid fields by changing the elements class and add a small icon nearby; this works great.  However, in addition to the highlighting, I'd like to display the messages defined in myMessages in either errorMessageLogin or errorMessageSignup based on the selection in the userAction radio group.  However, it appears that the value of errorLabelContainer is to be a jQuery object and not a function, which is unfortunate, since I'd be able to determine which error to show in a function.

Is it possible somehow to toggle the error container to be used by the jQuery Validation plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the errorPlacement callback inside your validate object to customize the placement of the created error labels. This function accepts two parameters: error and element.
An example from jQuery docs ( http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate):

```
$("#myform").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     error.appendTo( element.parent("td").next("td") );
   },
   debug:true
 })
```

Comment: I'm not certain how I can maintain the highlighting functionality that I have now, combined with the display of an error container based on errorMessageLogin or errorMessageSignup.  I find the documentation for this plugin to be a little thin.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why not? These are separate functions - one deals with error highlightning on the actual field where the error appears, and the other deals with the error message itself and it's placement.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at this question ?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532009/placing-error-message-for-a-checkbox-array

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you can't use two different forms? That would be an easier way to segregate the error message functionality? And just hide one form or the other?

Answer (score -1):

This is not tested, but rather an idea to start you on the path...

```
$("#myForm").validate({
submitHandler: function (form) {
    MyWebService.DoWork(form);
},
rules: myRules,
errorLabelContainer: function () {
    var rdoValue = $("input[name='userAction']:checked").val();
    // branch and return the container based on value...
},
messages: myMessages,
highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
    $(element).prev().addClass(errorIcon);
    $(element).addClass(errorClass);
    $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").addClass(errorClass);
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
    $(element).prev().removeClass(errorIcon);
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
    $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").removeClass(errorClass);
}
});
```

Comment: errorLabelContainer cannot be a function; as I mentioned, it must be a jQuery object.

Comment: Sorry, you are right I see that now.  In that case use of the errorPlacement seems to be the best way to resolve this...