# Placing error message for a checkbox array

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the Validation Plugin for jQuery and it works wonders. Except when I have a group of checkboxes...the error messages will display right after the first checkbox...like so:

[image]

```
<tbody>
     <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
             <input type="checkbox" name="selectItems" value="<c:out value="${item.numberPlate}"/>" />
          </td>
          <!--some other columns-->
         </tr>
      </c:forEach>                       
</tbody>
```

**------------------------------EDITED-------------------------**

I found that I can use **errorPlacement** , but I have no idea how to show **ONLY** the error message of the checkbox array in the table footer or somewhere else inside the second fieldset.

Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use a custom validation method ? Something like this:

**jQuery:**

```
// The custom validation method, returns FALSE (invalid) if there are
// no checkboxes (with a .one_required class) checked
$.validator.addMethod("one_required", function() {
    return $("#myform").find(".one_required:checked").length > 0;
}, 'Please select at least one vehicle.');

$("#myform").validate({
    // Use the built-in errorPlacement function to place the error message
    // outside the table holding the checkboxes if they are the ones that
    // didn't validate, otherwise use the default placement.
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if ($(element).hasClass("one_required")) {
            error.insertAfter($(element).closest("table"));
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myform">
    <!-- table, rows, etc -->
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="one_required" name="selectItems[]" value="NA245852" /></td>
    <td>NA245852</td>
    <!-- more rows, end table, etc -->
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go, baby !">
</form>
```

Since the jQuery Validate plugin can also validate an element if the method name is present as a `class`, simply output the `.one_required` class on all checkboxes.

See a [working demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8L5C2/) with multiple checkboxes.

**EDIT:**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8hWg/35/)'s your own code with the above solution implemented.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I don't know how to thank you , FreekOne and Cybernate, you both have been so supportive :D

Comment: @eddy - Glad to be of help ! :)

Comment: You do not need a custom method to validate a group of checkboxes.  Your custom method is no different than the default `required` rule.

Comment: @Sparky Indeed, you are correct on your first point. I was not aware back then that one can validate a group of checkboxes that require at least one to be checked by using the array notation in the name attribute (even though I see that I had that in my fiddle, weird). On your second point however, I believe the difference is obvious: the custom method does not require said array notation, not that there's anything wrong with it. TL;DR: people should use the array notation along with the default `required` method instead :)

Comment: As long as every checkbox in the group has the same `name`, it absolutely does not matter that the `name` contains a `[]` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can use errorLabelContainer configuration option..
define a **div with an id like errorMessages** and then change your validate method call as follows:

```
$("form").validate({
   errorLabelContainer: $("#errorMessages"),
     rules: ..... your rules
```

Now all the error messages will be displayed in the div.
**Edit: Updated the answer below to reflect the updates to the question:**
To change the location of error messages displayed, I can think of using the errorPlacement config parameter.
You can use something like:
Define a div or a p and keep appending the messages for the checkboxes to this element.

```
$("form").validate({
errorPlacement:function(error,element) {
    if (element.attr("name") == "selectItems") {
        //Add Code to append the error message to a predefined element
        $("#errorDiv").html("");
        $("#errorDiv").append("<YOUR_CUSTOM_MESSAGE>");
    } else { 
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
  },
  rules: ..... your rules
});
```

jsFiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8hWg/28/

**EDIT:**
Change your javascript to as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){        
                var formValidator = {};
                $("#Date").datepicker();       
                formValidator = $("#form1").validate({
                        errorPlacement:function(error,element) {
                                if (element.attr("name") == "selectedItems") {
                                                //Add Code to append the error message to a predefined element
                                        $("#errorDiv").html("Select at least one vehicle");
                                } else {
                                        error.insertAfter(element);
                                }
                        },

                        rules: {
                                avgTime:{
                                        required:true,
                                        number:true
                                },

                                selectedItems:
                                {
                                        required:true
                                },
                                Date:{
                                        required:true,
                                        date:true
                                }

                        },    
                        //onclick: true,
                        submitHandler: function(form) {
                                $("#errorDiv").html("");
                                form.submit();
                        }

                });       
                $("input[name=selectedItems]").bind("change", function() {
                        var me = $(this);
                        var scoper = me.parent().parent();
                        var otherInputs = $("input[name^=mileage]", scoper);
                        otherInputs.attr("disabled", !this.checked);
                        otherInputs.attr("value","");
                        if (this.checked)
                        {
                                otherInputs.addClass('required number');
                                $("#errorDiv").html("");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                otherInputs.removeClass("required number");
                        }
                        formValidator.element("input[name=selectedItems]");
                });


        });  
</script>
```

Comment: @Cybernate: Thank you, but as you say by using the errorLabelContainer all the error messages will be displayed in the same place and that's not what I need since I have two different sections in my form. I updated the image in my question to show how my whole form looks

Comment: @Cybernate: it does add the error message, but it does it for every single element of the array :( and ... it doesn't remove the error message when all the rules are met :(

Comment: You can define submitHandler in the validation configuration and reset the div. e.g submitHandler: function(form) {$("#errorDiv").html("");
   form.submit();
 }

Comment: @Cybernate- I tried what you told me, but the problem persists: If I have 5 check boxes, every time I click on one of them, either to check it or uncheck  it, a new error message appears on the div

Comment: Can you post the HTML at jsFiddle.net?

Comment: Edited the answer as per your request. Please check and let me know for any issues.

Comment: It works fine, but is there any way to make the error message appear/disappear immediately after I click on a chebox depending on whether at least one checkbox is checked or not?

Comment: Posted the changed version of JS in the answer as EDIT. Please try tht

Comment: It no longer adds a line with the error message every time I  click on a checkbox, but the error message does not disappear even if the rule is met. At the bottom of this page http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ there's an example very similar to what I want to achieve.

Comment: I tried it again but can see that the message disappears as soon as one checkbox is selected. Can you make sure you have taken the script as is?

Comment: It's very strange, in http://jsfiddle.net works fine but when I add it to my project  it doesn't. The error message simply does not dissapear  :(

Comment: Am out of any more thoughts :(