# jquery validate problem

Tags: jquery

hi i am using jquery validate plugin. I am using equalTo method for checking both password fields.

my password fields

```
<p><label for="password">Password:<span class="important">*</span></label><input id="password" type="text" name="password" class="required" /></p>
<p><label for="cpassword">Confirm Password:<span class="important">*</span></label><input id="cpassword" type="text" name="cpassword" class="required" /></p>
```

my jquery

```
$("#registeruser").validate({
                rules: {
                    username: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3,
                    remote: {
                        url: "checkuser.php",
                        type: "post",
                        data: {
                            username: function() {
                                    return $("#username").val();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 6
                    },
                    cpassword: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 6,
                        equalTo: "#password"
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true,
                        remote: {
                        url: "checkuser.php",
                        type: "post",
                        data: {
                            email: function() {
                                    return $("#email").val();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }           
                },
                messages: {
                    username: {
                        required: "Please enter a username",
                        minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 3 characters",
                        remote: "This username is already registered"
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: "Please provide a password",
                        minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long"
                    },
                    cpassword: {
                        required: "Please provide a password",
                        minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long",
                        equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
                    },
                    email: {
                        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                        remote: "This email is already registered"
                    }
                }
            });
```

everything else working fine except the equalTo method for the password and cpassword fields. minlength is working but not equalTo. I am entering same values in both fields but it is giving me error for invalid equalTo

Comment: Is there *another* `id="password"` field, possibly in another `<form>` earlier in the page?

Comment: Are both elements inside the same form? (The `password` and `cpassword` fields?

Comment: Can you please post (or link to a pastie/git gist page) with the full html for that page? The code for your validate plugin seems fine. Also, make sure you're using a compatible version of the form plugin and jQuery - that screwed me up with this plugin specifically. In addition, to isolate this error, make sure to copy your code into a separate page and ONLY include jquery and jquery.validate. Other scrips may be overriding something.

Comment: @Nick-Would you mind taking a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532009/placing-error-message-for-a-checkbox-array  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was another field with id password. That was creating problem.
Thanks